# CQL Filter on WMS

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, javascript, wms, cql-filter

I have CQL_Filter which filters WMS layer and displays only the points I asked for. The problem is that all features even the hidden, keep showing its popup when I click on their spot.

So, as I understand, I should apply filter also to my protocol or the control:

**1- for the protocol:**
Coz I use Protocol for selecting like so:

```
//select is empty vector layer 
var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({ 
        protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(wms, { 
            url: "http://IP/geoserver/wfs", 
            featureType: "wms" 
        }), 
        hover: false 
    }); 
   selectControl.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) { 
         select.addFeatures([e.feature]); 
           createPopup(e.feature); 

        else 
        e.feature.destroy();


});
```

**2-Or on the control:**

```
Var info=new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({ 
     layers: [wms], 
autoActivate: true, 
     maxFeatures: 3, 
    infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml", 
 eventListeners: { 
        "getfeatureinfo": function(e) { 
var items = []; 
            Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) { 
               items.push({ 
source: feature.attributes 
                }); 
                createPoup(feature);…
```

I have no idea how to accomplish that. Any help? 
Thanks in advanced.

**EDIT**

```
wms.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "type LIKE '%bird%'"});
```

I already have this line, it filtered the view only and returned all features.

Comment: I don't see a CQL filter in your code. It seems you're getting the entire layer. The CQL filter needs to be included along with your request to GeoServer Check out [this link](http://www.azavea.com/blogs/labs/2011/06/using-the-cql_filter-parameter-with-openlayers-wms-layers/)

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: Have you looked at this question and it's answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26452/how-to-use-cql-filter-in-openlayers-control-wmsgetfeatureinfo

Comment: This shows how you can use the cql_filter in WMSGetFeatureinfo: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-use-CQL-filter-in-OpenLayers-Control-WMSGetFeatureInfo-td4979761.html